# Can we add advanced text editors to a textarea in html page

Tags: javascript, api, tinymce, textarea, wysiwyg

Advanced text editors seems to provide text editing buttons within a `textarea` field, which can be similar to the bold, italics, quote and add picture buttons. I'm well aware of how to add text-editors (like `wysiwig`, `tinymce` etc.,) within a `Content management systems`(drupal, joomla), but I'm not sure whether we can add those `API`s to our simple html pages that contains a textarea field.

Does any one have any clue on how to add those APIs??

Comment: Read the instructions on the library webpages, and look at how the basic demo works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Quill](https://github.com/quilljs/quill) - A cross browser rich text editor with an API.

From the docs:

```
<!-- Create the toolbar container -->
<div id="toolbar">
  <button class="ql-bold">Bold</button>
  <button class="ql-italic">Italic</button>
</div>

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <div>Hello World!</div>
</div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="http://quilljs.com/js/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
  var editor = new Quill('#editor');
  editor.addModule('toolbar', { container: '#toolbar' });
</script>
```

Comment: How can i save this to database?

Comment: Grab the contents of the editor and post it to a script running on your backend that can make the database insert. You can do this on button press (e.g "Save" button), or whenever the user has typed something (you'll want to debounce that though).

Comment: So will I save them as html?

Comment: You can do that, sure. Use `quill.root.innerHTML` and see here: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/903

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
   <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
</head>
<body>
   <textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy & paste the snippet below into your HTML page

Comment: While MoxieManager may very well be what the OP is looking for, your answer doesn't explain how or why it would help, and linking to a potentially unknown .js file and recommending someone include that in their site is a huge security risk without knowing what the code actually does. I'd recommend rewording your answer to talk about MM and how it works and can solve the problem.

Comment: Please follow this link to know more! https://www.tinymce.com/download/